# How to show multiple images by ajax success

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, mysqli

I have Group_con the images by same date

```
$a  = "SELECT  dates AS p FROM imgdb  WHERE id=1 GROUP by dates";
```

Then Group_concat the images by date

```
foreach ($a as $value) {

 $res = SELECT  group_concat(images) AS img FROM imgdb  WHERE dates=$value";
}
```

And on ajax success

```
success: function(r) {
var res = JSON.parse(r)
$.each(res, function(index) {
   $('.img').html(
  $('.img').html()+'<img src"folder/'+res[index].img+'"/>'
}
```

I get images but on same line like ..

1.jpg,2.jpg,3.jpg etc..

And Console says no 404 not found ..

Thanks..

Comment: I highly doubt you need the `JSON.parse(r)`. at least add the `;` at the end

Comment: `404 not found`  - when does it say that?  When fireing the ajax? Then the url is wrong.

Comment: @jeff it is there i have kept it short

Comment: `$('.img').html(...` missing the closing `);`

Comment: @jeff images are shown on one <img src = 1.jpg, 2.jpg>" , so hence the error

Comment: _"I get images but on same line like"_ please show how you get them out of db and how you send them back.

Comment: Add a `=` after `src`  in '<img src"folder/' too.

Comment: `group_concat(images)` - you shouldn't do that. put them sperately in an array, json_encode that to send back.

Comment: @ jeff How to do  that

Comment: 'I get images but on same line like' you are getting image, so what actually the question is, you want in separate lines then add <br> after or before <img in.html

Comment: you want in separate lines then add <br> after or before, How whould that be in same date..

Comment: don't use group_concat , you will get result in array,  and you are using $.each for loop, so it will loop all imgs and add to html, use append

Comment: How can I show the images for exact date

Answer (score 0):

change query to something like this, i don't have mysql so not sure for correctness

```
SELECT dates, group_concat(images) AS img FROM imgdb  WHERE dates=$value
GROUP BY dates
```

i used postgress sql , and query like this

```
SELECT datum, array_to_string(array_agg(image), ',') as img FROM taböename   
 Where datum> '23.05.2018' AND datum< '23.08.2018'
GROUP BY datum
```

i got result like this

```
datum | img
23.08.2018 | img1,img2,img3
24.08.2018 | img1, img5
```

and so on

now return this to ajax

and this code will loop through the whole 2d array, print each with there images

```
    $.each(jQuery.parseJSON(objJson) , function (key, value) { 
        // add date
        $('#img_html').html(value.leiterdatum +'<hr>'); // hr adds a line
        var images = value.split(',');
        for(var i = 0; i < images.length; i++)
        {
            var new_img = '<img src="folder/'+images+'" alt="" /> </br>';
            $('#img_html').append(new_img);
        }
    })
```